# $http get dosn't work frome code but works with other rest client

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-headers, cross-domain

I have a problem with angular $http get with Authorization header.

I tried to excute the same request with different rest client and response are the same each one.

**Advanced Rest Client Chrome extension**
[image: Advanced Rest Client Chrome extension]

**Soap-Ui**
[image: Soap-ui]

**Insomnia**
[image: Insomnia]

I have always received the same response with 200 status code.

but when I try to make the same call from my angular application I get 403 status code and response is an OPTIONS.

[image: Angular Response]

where I'm wrong?

this is my code:

Config

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='Bearer 24ac24e6-0f9b-48b5-923f-b75986226bd9';
});
```

Service

```
app.service('DiscoveryService', function ($http) {
    this.getData = function (callbackFunc) {
        $http({
            url: 'https://test.test/test-api/source-monitor/v1/discover',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).error(function (error) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
});
```

Controller

```
DiscoveryService.getData(function (dataResponse) {
            $scope.data = dataResponse;
        });
```

Comment: Rest clients aren't subject to CORS restrictions the way browsers are. API is not CORS enabled

Comment: Thanks Charlietfl, I use third party Api to integrate my application with another product. I wanted to be sure before writing an email to the supplier of the service that the problem was not due to my mistake

Comment: Well a lot of api's aren't intended to be consumed by ajax either. Client side apps use a proxy in those cases

Comment: Do you suggest me  to use an intermediate level written in node or express?